# Reusable, generic save method

Tags: python, python-2.x, file

I am developing a Python script that will process large amounts of data from an experiment. Files are read in, calculations are made, images are plotted and saved as .pngs, and calculated parameters are outputted to a .txt file.

When I save a file, the user is prompted if they want to overwrite any existing files. If yes, a file overwrite is attempted. If the file is locked/open in another program, a number is appended to the filename and then saved. If they do not want to overwrite, a number is appended to the filename.

In order to not have redundant code, I wrote a generic "save" method:

```
def _handle_file_save(path, save, overwrite, *args):
    """
    Handles file collisions when saving files. If "overwrite" is true,
    overwrites file, if "overwrite" is false or the file to be overwritten
    is locked from editing, appends a number on end of filename to avoid
    file collision.

    Args:
        path (str): the path to the file to be saved
        save(): The save function used to save file
        overwrite (bool): true if user wants to overwrite file
        args: generic tuple of arguments used for different save functions

    """
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        if overwrite:
            try:
                print "Saving \"" + path + "\""
                save(path, args)
            # Signifies problem writing file (lack of permissions, open
            # in another program, etc.)
            except EnvironmentError:
                # save as incremented file number
                print "Whoops! Looks like %s is locked!" % path
                path = gen_alt_filename(path)
                save(path, args)
        else:
            # save as incremented file number
            path = gen_alt_filename(path)
            print "Saving as \"" + path + "\" instead"
            save(path, args)
    else:
        print "Saving \"" + path + "\""
        save(path, args)
    print "\n"
```

I pass in a generic save function and any arguments that save function needs if any. Some file outputs don't require any arguments.

Flaws:

- The client could pass in any arbitrary function as "save" and execute it. Is this a security risk?
- The variable `args` gets passed to the save function regardless of whether that method actually takes any args (i.e. args could be empty, but gets passed anyway.
- Doesn't check if appended filepath is also a locked/open file (could fix this with a while loop I suppose).

Possible improvements:

Use Python's `functools.partial` to reduce the function call's signature to one without "`args`" if `args` is empty.

Alternative:

- Instead of passing a generic save function, I could replace "`save(path, args)`" with "`new_file = open(path, 'w')`" (i.e. test file write, if successful, return the path to that file and write there).
- Don't merge code, let every save method handle its own collisions separately.

Nothing about any of this seems elegant. I'd greatly appreciate some advice on this, and how I can improve my coding strategies.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers!

Answer (score 8):

> Security risk? The client could pass in any arbitrary function as "save" and execute it.

A client can change your code, and it's there fault for not using the function as intended.

---

> variable "args" gets passed to the save function regardless of whether that method actually takes any args

```
save(path, *args)
```

This way it will see there is no arguments and not error.

---

> Instead of passing a generic save function, I could replace "save(path, args)" with "new_file = open(path, 'w')"

This is a better idea. This is as things like `json.dump` use a file object.
You could make it so that it works in a with statement, and return the file object.

---

```
print "Saving \"" + path + "\""
```

You should use `str.format`.

```
print "Saving \"{}\"".format(path)
```

---

You can add the ability of making it work with `with` statements with the below. If you want to know about these special functions look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers).

```
class _handle_file_save:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.file_handler = open(self.path)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.file_handler

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.file_handler.close()
```

Now, we can enter your function without the save parameter. This will allow us to do what you want.

```
class _handle_file_save:
    def __init__(self, path, overwrite, *args):
        self.path = path
        self.overwrite = overwrite
        self.args = args

    def _open(self):
        if os.path.isfile:

        # ... Just copy the rest.
```

However we now have the problem of

> Doesn't check if appended filepath is also a locked/open file

And so we can make it a recursive function!

```
class _handle_file_save:
    def _open_recursive(self, path):
        try:
            self.file_handler = open(path, *self.args)
            print "Saving \"{}\"".format(path)
        except EnvironmentError:
            self._open_recursive(gen_alt_filename(path))
```

Lets now get the `_open` function to work now.

```
class _handle_file_save:
    def _open(self):
        if os.path.isfile(self.path):
            if overwrite:
                self._open_recursive(self.path)
            else:
                self._open_recursive(
                    gen_alt_filename(self.path))
        else:
            self._open_recursive(self.path)
```

You may want to change it so there is only one if statement. However you may not want the first else to be recursive.

---

If we wrap it all up we get:

```
class _handle_file_save:
    def __init__(self, path, overwrite, *args):
        self.path = path
        self.overwrite = overwrite
        self.args = args
        self.file_handler = None

    def _open(self):
        if os.path.isfile(self.path):
            if overwrite:
                self._open_recursive(self.path)
            else:
                self._open_recursive(
                    gen_alt_filename(self.path))
        else:
            self._open_recursive(self.path)

    def _open_recursive(self, path):
        try:
            self.file_handler = open(path, *self.args)
            print "Saving \"{}\"".format(path)
        except EnvironmentError:
            self._open_recursive(gen_alt_filename(path))

    def __enter__(self):
        self._open()
        if self.file_handler is None:
            raise TypeError('self.file_handler never set.')
        return self.file_handler

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.file_handler.close()
```

You may want to change the error in `__enter__`.

This should work, however I don't know how to generate a locked file. But it seems like you know how to check.

Also it has the added support of allowing you to put all your file checking functions, I'm looking at you `gen_alt_filename`, into it to if you wish.

It's more complex, however it would work better then passing a save function as usage is just like `open`.

```
with _handle_file_save('file', False, 'rb') as file_:
    # Do something with `file_`
```

Comment: woah this is awesome! Thanks for the quick response. One of the main reasons I originally tried passing the save function is because I'm using the `plt.savefig(path)` function from `matplotlib` and therefore not explicitly handling any of the file saving myself. Can you imagine a way to incorporate that functionality with your method? Thanks!

Comment: awesome! I can't believe I missed that. I took another look at your code and modifed it some. Because `gen_alt_filename` only checks if a file exists when generating an alternate filename it won't help in the `except` branch on the `_open_recursive` call. I'll repost what I came up with now since it won't fit here..

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Joe Wallis' answer.
Because gen_alt_filename only checks if a file exists when generating an alternate filename it won't help in the except branch on the _open_recursive call. This SHOULD work, So:

Case 1: Append number to filename BEFORE attempting file save

Case 2: Attempt filesave, if exception thrown, append number and try again

```
class _handle_file_save:
    def __init__(self, path, overwrite, *args):
        self.path = path
        self.overwrite = overwrite
        self.args = args
        self.file_handler = None

    def _open(self):
        if os.path.isfile(self.path):
            if self.overwrite:
                self._open_recursive(self.path)
            else:
                n = 1
                path = self.path
                while os.path.isfile(self.path):
                    path = self._modify_filename(n)
                    n += 1
                self._open_recursive(path)
        else:
            self._open_recursive(self.path)

    def _open_recursive(self, path, n=1):
        try:
            self.file_handler = open(path)
            print "Saving \"{}\"".format(path)
        except EnvironmentError:
            path = self._modify_filename(n)
            n += 1
            self._open_recursive(path, n)

    def __enter__(self):
        self._open()
        if self.file_handler is None:
            raise TypeError('self.file_handler never set.')
        return self.file_handler

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.file_handler.close()

    def _modify_filename(self, n):
        root, suffix = os.path.splitext(self.path)
        path = "{}_({}).{}".format(
            root,
            n,
            suffix
        )
        return path
```